# Integrate Splidejs into Grapesjs: failing instanceof HTMLElement

Tags: angular, zonejs, grapesjs, splidejs

I am trying to integrate [Splidejs](https://splidejs.com/) into a [Grapesjs](https://grapesjs.com/) editor.
When mounting splides, I get the `Uncaught Error: [splide] A track/list element is missing.`

After debugging, I realise that Splide does not find the required track or list HTML Element for mounting properly. However, they are present in the HTML of the Grapes component.

```
...
<div class="splide__track">
<ul class="splide__list">
...
```

The reason why Splide doesn't find them seems to be related to different HTMLElement base types, leading to my elements not to be recognized.

The test below (Splide 3.6.9) returns `false`

[image]

When investigating in **Chrome dev tools console**, the `__proto__` chain evaluated by `instanceof` looks correct at first glance. However a closer look shows that `subject` has additionnal `__zone_symbol__onxxx` properties.

```
> subject.__proto__.__proto__
    HTMLElement {…}
        ...
        __zone_symbol__ononabortpatched: true
        __zone_symbol__ononanimationendpatched: true
        __zone_symbol__ononanimationiterationpatched: true
        ...
> HTMLElement.prototype
    HTMLElement {…}
        ...
        none of the __zone_symbol __onxxx present
        ...
> subject.__proto__.__proto__ == HTMLElement.prototype
    false
```

This could be explained by those two references:

(1) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof#instanceof_and_multiple_context_e.g._frames_or_windows

> `instanceof` and multiple context (e.g. frames or windows)
>
> Different scopes have different execution environments. This means that they
> have different built-ins (different global object, different
> constructors, etc.). This may result in unexpected results. For
> instance, `[] instanceof window.frames[0].Array` will return `false`,

(2) https://grapesjs.com/docs/modules/Components-js.html#important-caveat

> Keep in mind that all component scripts are executed inside the iframe
> of the canvas (isolated, just like your final template), and therefore
> are NOT part of the current document.

I am suspecting that my Splide content gets enhanced by zone.js.
Therefore I started creating the Grapes component outside of the Angular zone

```
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.initGrapesEditor()
    })
```

but the error remains.

Do you have any hints on how I could fix this issue?

- fully disable zone.js within my component hosting Grapes.js
- modify/fix the way Splide searches for (filters) the required HTML elements?
- other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also reported the issue on grapesjs' github
https://github.com/artf/grapesjs/discussions/4062

and added two workarounds

1. patching splidejs as follows (did not submit a PR).
   This allowed splidejs to be properly loaded by the script of my new component type.

as in

```
/**
 * Tests to see if the given TypeName appears anywhere
 * in the prototype chain of the given subject.
 * This is a lose version of the instanceof operator
 * (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)
 * required when checking the type of elements that cross window and iframe bouderies.
 * 
 * @param subject 
 * @param typeName 
 * @returns `true` if 
 */
function isInstanceOf(subject: any, typeName: string) {
  if (subject === null) {
    return false;
  }
  let p = subject.__proto__;
  while (p !== null) {
    if (p.constructor.name === typeName) {
      return true;
    }
    p = p.__proto__;
  }
  return false;
}

export function isHTMLElement( subject: unknown ): subject is HTMLElement {
  return isInstanceOf( subject, 'HTMLElement' );
}

export function isHTMLButtonElement( subject: unknown ): subject is HTMLButtonElement {
  return isInstanceOf( subject, 'HTMLButtonElement' );
}
```

2. replace [Splide](https://splidejs.com/) with [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/).
   Swiper does not rely on `instanceof HTMLElement` out of the box, which simplifies my development.